# Problem with setup suite in phpunit 8 and later

Tags: php, phpunit, test-suite

I have a package with many tests organized in suites. I want to upgrade phpunit compatibility from 7 to 8 and above, but I have a problem.
For each suite I have a setUp method which creates the database and populates it with the data to be used for tests within the suite. As of phpunit 8 it seems that this setUp method is no longer called and therefore all tests fail me. It doesn't seem to me that this is referenced in the documentation, has anyone had the same problem and knows how to fix it?

Comment: I just checked the most recent [PHPUnit](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/fixtures.html), 9.5, and those methods are still there.

Comment: No this methods aren't present in last version https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/src/Framework/TestSuite.php and are not called in "run"

Comment: I believe your problem is changing the signature of the setUp method, which now uses the return syntax enabled by php7. Apparently you need to replace public function setUp() {...} with public function setUp():void {...}

Comment: No this is not the problem, if you compare the **TestSuite** of version 7 with version 8 and 9 you can view that setUp and tearDown methods are not still present and the run method is change and not use it.

Comment: Those methods appear to be virtual: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/1c4fc0e68c42132b4bf38b0185058919f2dc3f31/src/Metadata/Api/HookMethods.php#L95, or what they call “templates”. I don’t know the specific reason why they are implemented this way, but one guess is to partially bypass inheritance

Answer (score 0):

`TestSuite` is nothing a user of PHPUnit should know about, let alone work with.